# TestNG object has 2 methods: run() and runSuitesLocally()

Tags: testng

I cannot find any info or documentation on these 2 methods.
What is the difference between:

```
  TestNG tng = new TestNG();
  tng.runSuitesLocally();
```

and

```
  TestNG tng = new TestNG();
  tng.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `runSuitesLocally()`:

> This needs to be public for maven2

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java#L1127-L1131

It means `runSuitesLocally()` should not be public and you are not supposed to use it.

From: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1006